# Sharepoint 2013 survey, page break and anonymous user access

Tags: 2013, survey

I made an anonymous survey for non-logged users. 
The problem is when I add page break (every 5 questions), the anonymous user can't click "Next" and carry on survey after page break, because he is getting prompted with login pop-out window.

Any way to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a permission problem resulting from a new popup survey window being generated automatically rather than by the user. I am running into a related issue where HTML in the question is being rendered as plain text if the HTML in question is after a page break. I do not have a solution that wouldn't be a compromise elsewhere.